# What is equivalent of rxjs pipe method in spring reactor?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

In Rx 5.5 there is a pipe method that allows applying a custom operator to the stream. Is there any equivalent of this for spring reactor?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that these two functions can be used for this purpose:

```
public final <V> Flux<V> compose(Function<? super Flux<T>, ? extends Publisher<V>> transformer) 


public final <V> Mono<V> compose(Function<? super Mono<T>, ? extends Publisher<V>> transformer)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct equivalent, but you could write reusable portions of operator chains by writing a `Function<Flux, Publisher>` that you pass to either `compose` (applying the function for each subscriber that comes in, allowing for dynamic behaviour in the function) or `transform` (applying the function during instantiation of the `Flux` operator chain, once).

For example:

```
Function<Flux<String>, Flux<Integer>> letterPerWordCount = f -> f
    .flatMap(sentence -> Flux.fromArray(sentence.split(" "))
    .map(String::length);

Flux<String> mySentenceSource;
Flux<Integer> letterCount = mySentenceCount.transform(letterPerWordCount);
```